# Flask. SQLAlchemy. How do INSERT with primary key?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

**The Situation:**

I have a flask application in which I need the functionality to insert a row into the database with a primary key.

**The Code:**

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "postgresql://example:example@example:5432/example"

db = SQLAlchemy()
db.init_app(app)


class TestModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'test'

    id = db.Column(primary_key=True, autoincrement=False)
    value = db.Column(db.String())


@app.route("/test", methods=['GET'])
def test():
    model = TestModel()

    model.id = 1234 # force set primary key
    model.value = 'Some string'

    db.session.add(model)
    db.session.commit()
```

**The Problem:**

The ORM seems to add the row wrong, as the following appears within the logs.

> ...
>
> [SQL: INSERT INTO test (value) VALUES (%(value)s)]
>
> ...

**What I require:**

I need it to perform SQL code similar to tha which follows.

```sql
INSERT INTO test (id, value)
VALUES      (1234, 'Some string')
```

**The Question:**

How can I get the flask-sqlalchemy ORM to insert the row with a preassigned primary key?

**Packages Used:**

> Python 3.9
>
> Flask 1.1.2
>
> Flask-SQLAlchemy 2.5.1
>
> SQLAlchemy 1.4.13

### EDIT...

**I do not know what happened. But I just restarted the server and my code started working as expected.

Thank you all for your help!**

Comment: Works as expected with `Flask==2.0.1`, `Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.5.1` and `SQLAlchemy==1.4.26`. Generated code  `[SQL: INSERT INTO test (id, value) VALUES (?, ?)]
[parameters: (1234, 'Some string')]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the class method to solve the problem.

```
class ModelName(db.Model)
  __tablename__ = ..
  id = ..
  name = ..


  @classmethod
  def add_modelname(cls,par1,par2):
     try:
      instance = ModelName()
      instance.id = par1
      instance.value = par2
      db.session.add(instance)
      db.session.commit()
      return instance
     except Exception as e:
      print(e)
```

..

```
@app.route("/test", methods=['GET'])
def test():
   id1 = 1
   value1 = "gvhcv"
   ModelName.add_modelname(id1 , value1)
   flash("Successful")
   return render_template("index.html")
```